# How does a calculated column work in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

How does acalculated column work in Sharepoint? When a calculated column is added to list, the next moment it'll update the list items. How does it happen?

Comment: Are you asking which SharePoint code updates the value of a calculated column?

Answer (score 2):

Calculated columns in SharePoint 2010 are similar to formulas in Excel spread sheet. Their result is attained by writing formula that uses the values of other columns (their names). There are all sorts of formulas to perform calculations as pointed out in the [Calculated Field Formulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) –msdn page, with example and possible result. You could also check the two links below that show steps of how to achieve a calculated column:

- [SharePoint: Creating Calculated Column Formulas](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.fi/2010/08/sharepoint-creating-calculated-column.html)
- [About SharePoint Calculated Columns](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/08/07/calculated-columns/)

Hopefully, this will make things more clear.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I understood what you've said. But my question how in back-end sharepoint updates all the list items as soon as calculated column is updated with the formula

Comment: "But my question how in back-end" - do you mean doing it with code yourself? This will be too long to explain. Other than this it's the built-in functionality that SP offers, same as it is e.g., with Excel; you use the given functions/formulas to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:** it updates the value when you save an item OR when you change the calculation in the field setting

read [this](http://sympmarc.com/2009/12/04/how-are-a-sharepoint-lists-calculated-columns-stored-and-rendered/) very interesting post. discussion in the comments section is very interesting.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've gone through the post you've mentioned. So it updates the list items on the save, but I've check fldNew.aspx but couldnt find anything. So still serching on

Answer (score 0):

Calculated fields are stored in Database and they are updated when you save an input.